# Processing of data in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have one file for a single day amounting to 30 files in a month.Each file contains 86400 lines with the following data format as shown below:
Hour Min Sec Value1 Value2 Value3 ......
However, the file contains lots of missing rows.So it becomes tedious to check each file
for inserting missing rows by using the interpolation.later on, i have to append one file after another to make a large file for each month (=86400*30 lines).Kindly suggest me any code that can compensate both time and labour.

Comment: have checked manually for each file to make sure that there should be no missing rows. then, i run this program A1= load('file1.txt'); ------------------ ----------------- A30= load('file30.txt'); B=[A1;A2.......A30]; B contains 86400*30 lines..........

Answer (score 1):

To read all files and stack data to form `B`,
you can use a loop over file names:

```
 for d = 1:30
     filename = sprintf('file%d.txt', d );
     A{ d } = load( filename );
     % complete missing values in A{d} here, for example using interpMissingRows below
     A{ d } = interpMissingRows( A{ d } );
 end
 B = vertcat( A{:} );
```

---

To compute missing entries, you may interpolate:

```
function interpData = interpMissingRows( data )
% compute seconds from 00:00:00 (assuming first entry is 0, 0, 0, val1 val2...
absSec = data(:,1:3) * [ 3600; 60; 1]; % matrix multiplication!
numValues = size(data,2) - 3; % number of colums to interpolate
totSec = 24*3600; % number of seconds in 24Hours
interpData = zeros(totSec, 3 + numValues ); % pre-allocate
interpData(:,1) = floor( (0:totSec-1)' / 3600 ); % hours
interpData(:,2) = floor( ( (0:totSec-1)' - interpData(:,1)*3600 ) / 60 ); % minutes
interpData(:,3) = mod(  (0:totSec-1)', 60 ); % seconds
interpData(:, 4:end) = interp1( absSec, data(:, 4:end), (0:totSec-1)', 'linear','extrap');
```

Comment: @Shai...I have run the code successfully for 1 or 2 files.But still I have found major error commented in the matlab as.Please Kindly rectify  it.....                                                                  ??? Error using ==> interp1 at 259 
The values of X should be distinct.

Error in ==> interpMissingRows at 10
interpData(:, 4:end) = interp1( absSec, data(:, 4:end), (0:totSec-1)', 'linear','extrap');
Error in ==> catenation at 8
A{ d } = interpMissingRows( A{ d } );

Comment: @PrasantaChingtham it would seems like one of your files has a duplicated line: that is two entries with the same hour, min, sec value.

Comment: @Shai...I have used unique to remove duplicacy in rows...                                                                                                                       A{d} = unique(A{d}, 'rows');it doesn't work.Any alternative to remove duplicated rows..

Comment: Additionally, i have also found that for the same time hour min and sec ie,values such as values1,values2 and values3..... are different in the data.

Comment: @Shai....Thanks for your help.One more problem araises....i have also found that for the same time hour min and sec ie,values such as values1,values2 and values3..... are different in the data.How can I rectify this....because A{d} = unique(A{d}, 'rows');it doesn't work.

Comment: @PrasantaChingtham please ask new question. It is very difficult to comprehend your problem from comment. Ask new question and link it to this one.

Comment: @ Shai..Ok...See \I have a file that should contain 86400 according to hour min sec.Unfortunately there are some lines that have same time but different values.But i want only one row out of this.So I used the   code A{d} = unique(A{d}, 'rows'); to remove duplicacy.But its not working.I request you that there is any alternative that can  remove this errors.

Comment: @PrasantaChingtham you need to do `unique` only for the day, hour, min  columns. Save the unique indices and then extract only the unique rows from `A{d}`. See help of `unique` to see how to get the unique indices.